# MS Access- order of occurrence

Tags: ms-access, count

I am struggling with the following thing in MS Access:  I want to assign each record an nth order of its occurrence (1st, 2nd time NOT TOTAL number of occurrences).

Comparing to Excel, it should work like countif with moving range. For example, if the values are stored in column B that would be

```
=countif($B$1:B1,B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my *RowCounter* function.

Please study the in-line comments for typical usage:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

Comment: And that you won't need. Just find a combination of fields that - when concatenated - will be unique for each record.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a correlated count subquery or conditional `DCount` for `SELECT` statements. Below assumes you have an autonumber field, *ID*, in *myTable*:

```sql
SELECT t.[value], (SELECT Count(*) FROM myTable 
                   WHERE sub.[value] = t.[value]
                   AND sub.ID <= t.ID) As value_rank
FROM myTable t

SELECT t.[value], 
       DCount("*", "myTable", 
              "[value] = " & t.[value] & " AND ID <= " & t.ID) As value_rank
FROM myTable t
```

For `UPDATE` queries, you would need the `DCount` for it to be an updateable query:

```sql
UPDATE myTable t
SET t.value = DCount("*", "myTable", 
                     "[value] = " & t.value & " AND ID <= " & t.ID)
```

If *value* is a string, wrap concatenation with single quotes: `... "[value] = '" & t.value & "' ...` If *value* is a date, wrap with hashtags: `... "[value] = #" & t.value & "# ...`